# Using J/Link with Wolfram Programming Cloud

Tags: java, wolfram-cloud

Is it possible to use J/Link in a Wolfram Programming Cloud notebook? I need it to load and use 3rd-party .jars.

Comment: initial testing revealed that OnlineM lets you load JLink with Needs["JLink`"], but then upon ReinstallJava[] the kernel quits. I've also seen that it uses Java 7 update 13, which is quite depressing, given that the current Java is Java 8 update 11 since Jul 15. I'd assume that CloudM uses the same as OnlineM, but haven't been able to test yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load Java in the cloud, in either the interactive web interface or in deployed code. (Some things are different about those environments.)

```
CloudEvaluate[
  Needs@"JLink`";
  str = JavaNew["java.lang.String", "Hello, world!"];
  JavaObjectToExpression[str]]
```

> "Hello, world!"

As pointed out by [Andreas Lauschke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1598/andreas-lauschke), `ReinstallJava[]` crashed the kernel in the programming cloud interface for me as well, but interestingly it does not crash here:

```
CloudEvaluate[
  Needs@"JLink`";
  ReinstallJava[];
  str=JavaNew["java.lang.String","Hello, world!"];
  JavaObjectToExpression[str]]
```

But it does not appear you can load jars, or edit the Java classpath.

```
jar = BinaryReadList@"HelloWorld.jar";
With[{j = jar},
 CloudEvaluate[
  path = "jars/HelloWorld.jar";
  CreateDirectory["jars"];
  BinaryWrite[path, j];
  Close[path];
  Needs@"JLink`";
  AddToClassPath[ClassPath -> path];
  {FileExistsQ@path, FreeQ[JavaClassPath[], path]}
  (*LoadJavaClass["HelloWorld"];
  Test`hello[]*)]]
```

> {True, True}

I guess this is for security reasons.

Comment: thanks for your answer. One clarifying question: how would you go about loading custom .jars in that environment? Is there a way to upload them to Wolfram Cloud? Or at least to access them from a remote location?

Comment: You can upload files to the WolframCloud either in the cloud (use up arrow next to the red "New" button) or use CopyFile[-local file-,CloudObject["cloud file name"]].  Also, in a Cloud notebook, you can load jar files present in the cloud.  You can't use CloudEvaluate or deployed APIFunctions to run Java code, as mfvonh has shown.